# Error generating sub components inside components with Angular CLI

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

Details: running OS 10.11, using Angular version 1.2.6, npm 5.3.0, node 8.2.0.

So I'm learning Angular for the first time, and I keep running into the same problem where if I create a new project using 'ng new [PROJECT]' and then use 'ng serve' it compiles and displays properly, but then if I try to use 'ng g c [NEW_COMPONENT]' then it breaks the project. Specifically, it says that 'Module Not Found: Error: Can't resolve [PATH]' and it gives a valid path for the component, the path that ng itself generated. What's going on here? I've tried uninstalling @angular/cli and node and npm several times and I can't seem to get Angular to reliably generate new components on its own. What am I doing wrong here?

---

```
ERROR in /Users/{USER}/Dropbox/angularprojects/shadowrun-inventory/src/app/app.module.ts (5,36): Cannot find module './src/app/inventory/inventory.component'.

ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Could not resolve ./src/app/inventory/inventory.component relative to /Users/{USER}/Dropbox/angularprojects/shadowrun-inventory/src/app/app.module.ts., resolving symbol AppModule in /Users/{USER}/Dropbox/angularprojects/shadowrun-inventory/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /Users/{USER}/Dropbox/angularprojects/shadowrun-inventory/src/app/app.module.ts

ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/app/inventory/inventory.component' in '/Users/{USER}/Dropbox/angularprojects/shadowrun-inventory/src/app'
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts 10:0-77
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts

webpack: Failed to compile.
```

This is the error I receive. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: may be because of using short hand for generating component for the first time.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message you receive?

Comment: Okay, update, it also seems to fail when I run 'ng g c [COMPONENT]' from inside the src/app directory, but DOESN'T fail when I run it from the root directory of the project. I just had it fail on me the same way, and the only thing I did differently was generate a sub-component from inside the /src/app directory instead of root. When I ran it from the root directory, it worked just fine.